# SIP Invite message python

Tags: python, networking, sip

I want to send a SIP Invite message from a client to a server using a known port. But, I don't know how to send a SIP message from a socket.

I know that the server is listening a port. How can I send a SIP message through a client?

I don't know how to form a SIP message, how can I add dest. IP address, dest. port#, my IP address, my Port#? Is there anything to add to this message? Is there a class for SIP message where I can fill inside of it?

I can send a TCP message through sockets, I know that. But this area(SIP) is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library like https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone. It´s multi platform and multi language (since you dont mention which platform you want) to send the SIP request from or the language you want to use

There is a python wrapper available

You register by indicating the IP address and the port of the SIP proxy  and then I guess you invoke the method call() that will trigger a SIP INVITE